# What can interfere with testing a server's performance?

Tags: performance, testing, load-testing

My HTTP server can't take load tests... It gives really high latency when multiple connections are made.

Server Configuration:
5 instances of (CPU 0.5vCore, Memory 512MB, Disk 20GB)
A load balancer
10G shared bandwidth

When I transfer a 3.5mb zip, it takes about 1second when there is only one connection. However, when over 30 connections are made, it goes up to 20~50 seconds.

I am testing with JMeter on my laptop. Is there a possibility that my testing environment interferes with the load-testing?

If so, what would be a solution to improve my testing environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to monitor and pin down the problem(s).

Start off by picking up information on these four layers:

- CPU Usage
- Memory Usage
- Network Usage
- I/O Usage

All of them on the OS layer. (Monitoring tools will vary depending on your OS).

Once you have this data and you can narrow the problem path (CPU bound, network latency, I/O latency or whatever) an answer will kick in. Also doing this (if it is the first time you are trying to test your app) will help you get scaling information on your environment and your application in general.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a headway to start. I am using centos6.3. Is there a comprehensive tool that monitors all the things mentioned above?

Comment: Far as I know CentOS is Linux based. I have never used it but I am assuming some linux utilities must be installed and/or can be installed. You can rely on OS utilities like:

ps , iostat, top, mpstat , vmstat, sar for a start (you can look them up on google or in man pages for further information)

I do reccomend you read Java performance by Charlie Hunt, your application might not be Java based but there is one whole chapter dedicated to Performance Monitoring on the OS Layer.